Do you think we need more mods from different time zones?
From time to time (like today) we get some spam on this website. As I've noticed, all our mods are online at a similar time and thus not all time zones are covered. Do you think we need one or two more mods to cover a few other time zones so we would have some wider mod presence coverage?

DH usually takes what those of us in the U.S. would refer to as "the night shift" - plus we've got awesome high-rep users who handle things quite nicely in our absence. I'm cleaning up those questions now, though.

Doesn't answer the main question, but I just got the URLs that are being spammed blacklisted by an SE admin, so we shouldn't see any more of that particular troublemaker.

I've had less time for moderating than usual lately but I think I'll be able to step it up a bit again. The monthly stats tells me that there has been 120 flags with an average handling time of 3 hours and 38 minutes. I would say that that's acceptable but not great.
As far as I know all of us have day jobs (and probably other interests too) so it is obviously hard for us to cover 24/7. In my opinion it wouldn't hurt to have a fourth moderator but it might be more important to strive for an active community (how do we do that?). I believe that if the community works well there shouldn't really be much work left for the moderators.
Anyway, if we're gonna have another moderator his name obviously needs to be David. ;)

Last part reminds me a bit of this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rexKqvgPVuA#t=272s (joke at 4:45-4:50)
